# How to check specific library version present inside python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes

Taking example. I see Latest Kubernetes python client release i.e. 27.2.0.  I would like to know how I can check version of other packages inside this latest Kubernetes release.
example  I want to know version of certifi inside Kubernetes module

On my RHEL box, I installed Kubernetes but the command PIP show Kubernetes just shows main version.

Comment: It's not "version of certifi inside kubernetes module" - the dependencies are not embedded inside other packages, they're installed together in whatever interpreter you used. So just `pip list` to list all installed packages and you'll find certifi and other stuff there

Answer (score 0):

just run:

```
pip list
```

it will list the version off all packagess

Comment: I can see certifi version in requirement.txt  when I unzipped source code.